# sql count (including null) from table where two conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables one is team_stats and the other is team_summary.
There are 16 tNames in team_summary and 1 means win, 0 means lose in win_lose column on team_stats.

```
team_summary            team_stats
tName W                 Period tName win_lose
AUT   null              1      AUT   1
CAN   null              2      AUT   1
DEN   null              3      AUT   1
FIN   null              Total  AUT   1
...                     1      CAN   0
                        2      CAN   0
                        ...
```

I want to insert into W column on team_summary.
When I query

```
select tName, count(*) from team_stats 
where Period='Total' and (win_lose) = 1 group by tName;
```

returns like this with 14 rows not including 0 count.

```
tName count(*)
AUT   1
CAN   6
DEN   4
...
```

I want to take 16 rows including those 14 values and 2 values which are 0 (or null).

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you really have a total row for each team  and if so why isn't it the sum of all the periods and why do you need to group by?

Comment: @P.Salmon   1,2,3, Total are included in each game. I want to sum to get that information  in a season.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want an `update`:

```
update team_summary ts left join
       (select tName, count(*) as wins
        from team_stats 
        where Period = 'Total' and (win_lose) = 1 
        group by tName
       ) t
       on ts.tName = t.tName
    set ts.summary = coalesce(t.wins, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps me out!

Comment: Do you mind if you explain that query? I am trying to understand but I want to know exact one. Especially, why do we need left join in that case?

Comment: @skJin . . . You need t use `left join` because you want to update all rows in `team_summary`, not just the ones that match the conditions in the `where`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - by removing `win_lose = 1` from your where clause

```
select tName, count(*) from team_stats 
group by tName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 16 teams in team_stats and each of them has the "Total" information, then you simply need:

```
select tName, win_lose from team_stats 
where Period='Total';
```

If you wish to know how many times each team appears in the team_stats table:

```
select tName, count(tName) from team_stats
group by tName;
```